# Solved ODE, how did answer key rewrite solution to be in this form?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I was solving the ODE $\frac{dx}{dt} = 4(x^2+1)$ with initial condition $x(\frac{\pi}{4})=1$
I got $\tan^{-1}{x} = 4t+c$
Then I plugged in the initial value and rewrote to get $\tan^{-1}{x}=4t+\tan^{-1}{1}-\pi$.
Some how the answer key got $x=\tan{(4t-\frac{3\pi}{4})}$ and I'd like to know how?

By the way, I'm not sure how to tag this question.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that $\tan^{-1}1 = \frac{\pi}4$. Then your equation becomes $\tan^{-1}x = 4t-\frac{3\pi}{4}$. Taking inverses of both sides, one obtains $x = \tan(4t-\frac{3\pi}{4})$.

Comment: Ugh I didn't know $tan^{-1}1=\frac{\pi}{4}$ for a differential equations course I didn't think I would have to memorize common trigonometric values and my calculator spat out gibberish when I imputed $tan^{-1}1$.

Comment: @Celeritas This is probably one of a couple of values of arctan I actually remember. Since $\tan = \sin/\cos$, it suffices to find an $x \in [-\pi,\pi]$ for which $\sin(x) = \cos(x)$, and the right $x$ is $\pi/4$.

Answer (score 0):

Take $x=\tan\left(4t+c\right)$ as the solution, and plug in the initial condition to get $x=\tan\left(4t-3\pi/4\right)$.